# Why is this beat detection code failing to register some beats properly?

Tags: c#, audio

I made this SoundAnalyzer class to detect beats in songs:

```
class SoundAnalyzer
{
    public SoundBuffer soundData;
    public Sound sound;
    public List<double> beatMarkers = new List<double>();

    public SoundAnalyzer(string path)
    {
        soundData = new SoundBuffer(path);
        sound = new Sound(soundData);
    }

    // C = threshold, N = size of history buffer / 1024  B = bands
    public void PlaceBeatMarkers(float C, int N, int B)
    {
        List<double>[] instantEnergyList = new List<double>[B];
        GetEnergyList(B, ref instantEnergyList);
        for (int i = 0; i < B; i++)
        {
            PlaceMarkers(instantEnergyList[i], N, C);
        }
        beatMarkers.Sort();
    }

    private short[] getRange(int begin, int end, short[] array)
    {
        short[] result = new short[end - begin];
        for (int i = 0; i < end - begin; i++)
        {
            result[i] = array[begin + i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    // get a array of with a list of energy for each band
    private void GetEnergyList(int B, ref List<double>[] instantEnergyList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < B; i++)
        {
            instantEnergyList[i] = new List<double>();
        }
        short[] samples = soundData.Samples;

        float timePerSample = 1 / (float)soundData.SampleRate;
        int sampleIndex = 0;
        int nextSamples = 1024;
        int samplesPerBand = nextSamples / B;

        // for the whole song
        while (sampleIndex + nextSamples < samples.Length)
        {
            complex[] FFT = FastFourier.Calculate(getRange(sampleIndex, nextSamples + sampleIndex, samples));
            // foreach band
            for (int i = 0; i < B; i++)
            {
                double energy = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < samplesPerBand; j++)
                    energy += FFT[i * samplesPerBand + j].GetMagnitude();

                energy /= samplesPerBand;
                instantEnergyList[i].Add(energy);

            }

            if (sampleIndex + nextSamples >= samples.Length)
                nextSamples = samples.Length - sampleIndex - 1;
            sampleIndex += nextSamples;
            samplesPerBand = nextSamples / B;
        }
    }

    // place the actual markers
    private void PlaceMarkers(List<double> instantEnergyList, int N, float C)
    {
        double timePerSample = 1 / (double)soundData.SampleRate;
        int index = N;
        int numInBuffer = index;
        double historyBuffer = 0;

        //Fill the history buffer with n * instant energy
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            historyBuffer += instantEnergyList[i];
        }

        // If instantEnergy / samples in buffer < instantEnergy for the next sample then add beatmarker.
        while (index + 1 < instantEnergyList.Count)
        {
            if(instantEnergyList[index + 1] > (historyBuffer / numInBuffer) * C)
                beatMarkers.Add((index + 1) * 1024 * timePerSample); 
            historyBuffer -= instantEnergyList[index - numInBuffer];
            historyBuffer += instantEnergyList[index + 1];
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason it's only detecting beats from 637 sec to around 641 sec, and I have no idea why. I know the beats are being inserted from multiple bands since I am finding duplicates, and it seems that it's assigning a beat to each instant energy value in between those values.

It's modeled after this: http://www.flipcode.com/misc/BeatDetectionAlgorithms.pdf

So why won't the beats register properly?

Comment: Can you post a plot of the evolution of instantEnergyList[index + 1] and historyBuffer over time for one band?  The two graphs overlayed on top of each other.  That would give clues about what the problem might be.  Also, energy must be the square of the magnitude, don't forget that.

Comment: Ahh yes that might unveil the problem, let me see if I can somehow make some graphs

Comment: Started making the graphs only there are 27000 samples for the whole song so I can't make it for the whole song, only for a part of song. this is the graph for the first 46 secconds on band 3 http://i.cubeupload.com/d169df.png

Comment: Where Red = instant and Green is history, and top = 0 As you can see the instant energy is hugging zero

Comment: But this plot is just historyBuffer, or historyBuffer/numInBuffer*C ?  It looks like you have a massive C in there.  Looking at the code, historyBuffer should have similar values to instantEnergy, that graph can only be if C is too high or numInBuffer is too low (way below 1), which I guess it's not the case.

Comment: In other words, can you check the graph with just historyBuffer? How big is your threshold C?

Comment: forgive if this is misunderstood, doesn't the line: 
 if(instantEnergyList[index + 1] > (historyBuffer / numInBuffer) * C) 
miss the actual check outlined on page 7 of the attached pdf? it says that comparing C*<E> was the detection (algorithm 3). looking up the page you can see that <E> denotes the average local energy * the same energy value that is then stored in index[0] * ... your code never checks index[0].

Comment: The question that _wouldn't die_...

Comment: Sorry - a bit late to the party, and my c++ ain't all that hot.. What is a "band"? where is it defined in the code?

Comment: @Joe: Pity that it's C# then :P

Comment: hah but seriously is this a predefined c# thing or is it in the code somewhere and I'm missing it

Comment: Where are you accounting for `(B[0]) and (B[1]) corresponding to the left an and right bn channels history`?

Comment: Try asking this question on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: from where come those SoundBuffer and Sound classes? I want to give it a shot...

Comment: @fableal Well the OP is long gone now, it'll be hard to get any more info. Maybe we should just close this question...

Answer (score 7):

I took a stab at it, which was dumb because I not familiar with Fourier transforms or music theory.  So, after some study I don't have a solution, but I see several troubling things:

- The code for the Sound and Soundbuffer is missing and could be easily be the culprit
- The Fourier Transforms

  - I couldn't find the same Fourier transforms library by googling the namespace and method names, which means that code might be custom and could be the source of the problem
  - The fact that FastFourier.Calculate takes an array of short is unusual
- The method GetEnergyList takes a ref List but this list isn't used again?
- In several spots you see the SampleSize hard coded to 1024, but it isn't clear that is always the case.
- It is troubling that the comment for PlaceBeatMarkers notes that N should be divided by 1024, maybe the calling code forgot to do that?
- I'm very suspicious of the way historyBuffer is manipulated in PlaceMarkers, especially since N is passed in and then used to manipulate the historyBuffer.
- The comment `*// Fill the history buffer with n * instant energy*` and the code that follows doesn't jive.

After a while I just got the feeling the code isn't really organized well and it'd be a waste of time trying to fix.  If you think it is worth it, the next step I'd take is:

1. Break it down to the most simplest part
2. Rewrite the code in
   the most verbose way, name all the hidden variables
3. Write unit
   tests to make sure that little part of code works correctly
4. Add another small section of code and repeat until you've got the whole
   thing working right

**Tips**

- You might want to make the number of bands fixed to simplify the loop logic
- Give variable like N, C and B good names that are clear and concise, this will help you mind see logical errors easier
- Break big sections of code into several called methods that each do a small concise step of the bigger process and can have unit tests written to ensure it is working correctly.

Comment: I'm a fan of solving code riddles, as long as the riddle is good.  Hence the bounty.  I'm glad you took it, and your answers for finding errors in code are the best answer a code riddle could get.